# Problemas con dimensiones de imagenes

Tags: html, css

estoy implementando una pagina de productos con react directo desde una api de productos (fake), pero las imagenes no aparecen de la misma dimension como podria tener las imagenes del mismo alto y ancho con el css. Estuve intentando este codigo:

```
    // React
    import React from 'react';

    // Axios
    import axios from 'axios';

    // Style
    import './style.sass';

    class Products extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                products: []
            }
        }

        componentDidMount = async() => {
            const products = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
            const { data } = products;

            this.setState({
                products: data
            });
        }

        productsCards = () => {
            const { products } = this.state;
            console.log(products)

            if(products.length < 1) return <h1>No existen productos disponibles</h1>;
            
            return products.map(({image, title, price, category}, ix) => {
                return(
                    <div className="product-card">
                        <div className="product-image-container">
                            <img src={image}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="product-card-description">
                            <div className="card-product-title">
                                <p>{title}</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className="card-product-category">
                                <p>{category}</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className="card-product-price">
                                <p>{price}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="product-card-single-button">
                            <p>Ver producto</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <div className="products-wrapper">
                    <div className="products-container">
                        {this.productsCards()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default (Products);
```

y el css:

```
    .products-wrapper
        margin: 0 auto

        & > .products-container
            display: grid
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr))
            grid-column-gap: 4em
            grid-row-gap: 3em

            & > .product-card
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)

                & > .product-image-container
                    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px
                    height: auto
                    width: 100%
                    
                    & > img
                        height: 100%
                        max-width: 100%
                        width: auto
```

Pero me sigue saliendo como la imagen adjunta:

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAyRY.png)

Answer (score 0):

encontre por alli una salida y fue pasar la imagen que me retorna de la api como background del contenedor

```
<div className="product-image-container" style={{backgroundImage:  `url(${image})` }}>
</div>
```

para el css:

```
      & > .product-image-container
            max-width: 100%
            height: 300px
            background-position: 50% 50%
            background-size: contain
            background-repeat: no-repeat
```